# Different behavior in TypeScript type when behind generic type

Tags: typescript

I am seeing confusing behavior in tsc 3.2.2.  I have two types that I expect to be equivalent but are not (according to VSCode intellisense - is there a better way to check?).

First, I have a discriminated union discriminated by a `type` key.  The idea is that I will look up the proper type via the discriminant and then remove the `type` key to get the payload type:

```
interface A { type: 'a', x: number }
interface B { type: 'b', y: string }
type Request = A | B
```

I have some helper types.  `Omit` comes from the TS docs, and `Discriminate` takes a discrimated union, the discriminant key, and the value for that key to use in the lookup and produces the matching type from the union:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type Discriminate<T, U extends keyof T, V extends T[U]> = 
  T extends Record<U, V> ? T : never
```

Now I define a helper to get the `Request` variant by `type` key:

```
type RequestType<T extends Request['type']> = Discriminate<Request, 'type', T>
type A2 = RequestType<'a'> // Equals A, good so far
```

Now I add a helper to get the `Request` payload type by `type` key:

```
type RequestPayload<T extends Request['type']> = Omit<RequestType<T>, 'type'>
type APayload = RequestPayload<'a'> // {} - That's not right!
```

However, if I calculate the payload type more directly, it works:

```
type APayload2 = Omit<RequestType<'a'>, 'type'> // { x: number } - Correct
```

**What is the difference between `APayload` and `APayload2`?**  Is this maybe a bug?  I think it's far more likely that I'm missing something.   They seem like they should be identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the tooltip for the definition of `RequestType`, it's actually a union type:

```
type RequestType<T extends "a" | "b"> = Discriminate<A, "type", T> | Discriminate<B, "type", T>
```

When you use `Omit` on it, `keyof` in the `Omit` goes only over the keys that are present in all the members of the union, that is, `Omit` only sees the `type` key and nothing else, and when you omit it the resulting type comes as empty.

You need to use special version of `Omit` to fix it. You need `UnionOmit`that "[distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)" `Omit` over the members of the union then immediately assembles the union back again:

```
type UnionOmit<T, K> = T extends {} ? Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> : never;


type RequestPayload<T extends Request['type']> = UnionOmit<RequestType<T>, 'type'>
type APayload = RequestPayload<'a'>  // {x: number}
```

Comment: I feel kinda dumb that I didn't notice it was a union.  But based on your answer, I'd expect the last line of my example to get the wrong result too.  Can you explain the difference?

Comment: The last line of your example uses `Omit` on one member of the union, selected by `'a'` - if you write for example `type T = RequestType<'a'>;` you will see in the tooltip that `T = A`.

Comment: It also makes me wonder *why* it's a union.  I didn't expect a union in a type parameter to get distributed without a conditional type.

Comment: because `RequestType` is a type alias for `Descriminate`, and that's a conditional type, using it's first type parameter in a condition `T extends Record<U, V> ?`

Comment: Yeah I guess I expected it to substitute the type arg once a concrete type was there.  I find this behavior to be confusing still because they *look* the same.

Comment: On a side note, I just realized I'm an idiot and spelled 'discriminate' wrong, but only in the type.